# unable to find {Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape} control in form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

IDE: VS 2010, c# .net 4.0, Winforms

As we know we can find control using name by following way

Example for Panel Control:

```
Control[] c = this.Controls.find("panel1", true);  
if(c.length>1)
{
  Panel p = c[0] as Panel;
}
```

above code is working.

The same code I used for rectangle shape control which name space is

```
{Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape}
```

and I added rectangle shape on form named "rectangleShapeMonthCalender"

```
Control[] c = this.Controls.find("rectangleShapeMonthCalender", true);  
if(c.length>1) //here I am getting length of control array 0, i.e control not found.
{
  Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape shape= c[0] as Panel;
}
```

can you tell me how to find back control which resides in

```
"Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks"
```

namespace,  so I can solve above problem.

Comment: Is your control name `rectangleShapeMonthCalender1`?

Comment: my control name is rectangleShapeMonthCalender, which is type of Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape

Answer (score 0):

Shapes such as rectangle,oval etc resides in shapecontainers, so whenever we add rectangle in form automatically shapecontainer is added on that form.

to find that rectangle back use following code:

```
         int totalItems = shapeContainer1.Shapes.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++)
            {
                Shape s = container.Shapes.get_Item(i) as Shape;

            }
```